# Finding $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2 + \sin 2x} dx$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to find the value of $$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{2 + \sin 2x} dx. $$

I tried to substitute $\sin 2x = \frac{2 \tan x}{1 + \tan^2 x}$, knowing that $\tan x$ is discontinuous  at $n \frac{\pi}{2}$, where $n$ is an odd integer.
Finally I got the integral as $$ \frac{\tan^{-1}\big(\frac{2 \tan x + 1}{\sqrt{3}}\big)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Now, I thought of trying to break the function from 0 to $ \pi/2$, $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ and so on till $2\pi$ and tried to find the value but I cannot find it.
How to proceed from here now?

Comment: I wouldn't expect this substitution to really help you. How well do you know complex analysis or have you ever heard of Weierstraß substitution?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of it. Is my approach wrong?

Comment: Your approach is very close to Weierstrass substitution. Normally in Weierstrass substitution you use $t = \tan (x/2)$ and obtain $\sin x = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, but due to the $2x$, you can change up what $t$ is slightly for an easier eval

Comment: @gist076923 But how this would help since the function will still be discontinuous?

Comment: Use residue theorem

Comment: $\tan\left(n\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ is undefined when $n$ is odd. And did you mean to do the substitution $\sin\left(2x\right)=\frac{2\tan\left(u\right)}{1+\tan^{2}\left(u\right)}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before using the Weierstrass substitution, we should be aware of the discontinuity of $\tan x$. We overcome this by first restricting the interval by symmetry of $\sin x$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{1}{2+\sin 2 x} d x \\
& =2 \int_0^\pi \frac{1}{2+\sin 2 x} d x \\
& =2 \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{1}{2+\sin 2 x} d x
\end{aligned}
$$
If we let $t=\tan x$, we obtain $\sin(2x) = \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$ and $d x = \frac{1}{1+t^2} d t$

Thus we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2+\frac{2 t}{1+t^2}}\cdot \frac{1}{1+t^2} d t\\
& =4 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{4 t^2+4 t+4} d t \\
& =4 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2 t+1)^2+3} d t \\
& =\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 t+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty} \\
& =\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\frac{\pi}{2}-\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\right] \\
& =\frac{2 \pi}{\sqrt{3}}
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\int_0^{\pi } \frac{1}{2+\sin  2x} \, dx=\int_{-\pi /2}^{\pi /2} \frac{1}{ 2-\sin  2y} \, dy=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{1-t+t^2} \, dt$$

using $y=x-\pi /2$ and $t= \tan  y$